# I'm trying to make a javascript drawing program within the browser and things are misaligned. Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I've been working on this really basic drawing program for a while now and just can't seem to get it to work correctly.

The user can draw in the canvas element now, but things are somehow misaligned; the lines appear far from the cursor when you attempt to draw, and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Here's my code...

html

```
<div class="info">
    
  <canvas id="canvas" height="480" width="640" style="border:1px solid #000000; width: 640px; height:480px; background-color: white">Please update your browser.</canvas>
  <script src="paint.js"></script> 
    
</div>
```

javascript

```
// paint.js
(function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //resizing
  //canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  //canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

  //variables
  var painting = false;

  function startPosition(e) {
    painting = true;
    draw(e);
  }

  function endPosition() {
    painting = false;
    context.beginPath();
  }

  function draw(e) {
    if (!painting) return;
    context.lineWidth = 7;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.strokeStyle = "green";

    context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }

  //EventListeners
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `clientX` and `clientY` with `offsetX` and `offsetY` to get the right coords according to mouse position inside the element

you can read more about MouseEvent and figure out the differences between

```
clientX/Y
screenX/Y
offsetX/Y
```

try the snippet

```js
// paint.js
(function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //resizing
  //canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  //canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

  //variables
  var painting = false;

  function startPosition(e) {
    painting = true;
    draw(e);
  }

  function endPosition() {
    painting = false;
    context.beginPath();
  }

  function draw(e) {
    if (!painting) return;
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.strokeStyle = "green";

    context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  }

  //EventListeners
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
})();
```

```css
div {
  width: 460px;
  height: 460px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
    
  <canvas id="canvas" height="460" width="460" style="border:1px solid #000000; background-color: white">Please update your browser.</canvas>
  <script src="paint.js"></script> 
    
</div>
```